# Python - Exclude contents of one file from another / removing duplicate lines amongst two files

Tags: performance, python-2.7, duplicates, text-files, large-files

first off, i'm using python 2.7.9 .....
now, i'm trying to find the most efficient way to compare the lines of one text file (file A) to the lines of another text file (file B) and write all lines that are unique to file A into a new file (file A\B).

actually i've written a short script that does this, but it is beyond slow...
i need the script to be able to handle files of up to 70mb(each, A&B),
which is unthinkable with this 'bad' boy:

```
import string
naked = string.strip
kiss = ''.join

def main():
    list1 = raw_input("Enter name of .txt-file to clean!\n")
    list2 = raw_input("Enter name of .txt-file to exclude!\n")
    action(list1, list2)
    raw_input("Done!\nPress [ENTER] to exit!")

def action(list1, list2):
    f = open(kiss([list1, '.txt']), "r")
    g = open(kiss([list2, '.txt']), "r")
    h = open(kiss([list1, '_without_', list2, '.txt']), "w")
    h_w = h.write
    reset = g.seek
    found = False
    for i in f:
        found = [True for j in g if naked(i) == naked(j)]
        if not found:
            h_w(kiss([naked(i), '\n']))
        else:
            found = False
        reset(0)
    f.close()
    g.close()
    h.close()

main()
```

yeah... does anyone have any idea how to do this more efficiently?!
thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look over this:https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html if you have no ram restrictions (70mb seems not to) I think is a good option

Comment: thanks, mmap looks promising! but can you explain how to use the offset param? and what is this "ALLOCATIONGRANULARITY" ?! (i want to try to map at least one of the files in chunks to reduce mem.consumption)

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as src:
        return [line.strip() for line in src.readlines()]


def main():
    list1 = raw_input("Enter name of .txt-file to clean!\n")
    list2 = raw_input("Enter name of .txt-file to exclude!\n")
    file1 = read_file(list1)
    file2 = read_file(list2)
    file3 = open('new_file.txt', 'w')

    for line in file1:
        if line not in file2:
            file3.write(str(line) + '\n')  # writes to a new file

    file3.close()
    print 'Completed'

main()
```

I am not sure this is fastest way but it will do the trick. you can use "diff" or "comm" linux commands to get the required output.